# $\mathcal{O}_{\mathsf{Proj} \: A}(\mathsf{Proj} \: A)=A$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

It's very well known that if one takes an affine scheme $X=\mathsf{Spec} \: A$, then  $\mathcal{O}_X(X)=A$. Now my question is if the same works for a scheme $X=\mathsf{Proj} \: A$.

Comment: -1. the simplest counterxample works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true. For instance, projective space over a field $k$ is defined as $\Bbb P^n:=\operatorname{Proj}k[x_0,\dots,x_n]$, but it's a basic fact that $\Gamma(\Bbb P^n,\mathcal O_{\Bbb P^n})=k$.

Comment: Is it true that $\Gamma(proj A, O_A)=A_0$?

Comment: @user45878 I feel pretty confident that the answer is no, but I don't have an example off the top of my head. I'll try to think of one, and if I find one I'll update

Comment: The answer should be no, indeed. The scheme $\operatorname{Proj}(A)$ is a proper $A_0$ scheme and so its global sections are a number of copies of $A_0$. To be precise, for every connected component we get a copy of $A_0$.